# How to determine the time an actuator has been enabled during the past x minutes?

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, esp32, arduino-esp32

I need to find the most efficient approach to the following. If someone can point me in the right direction, I can write the code myself.

**Environment**
I am using an ESP32 and working in Arduino C++.

**What I want to achieve**
I want to track the amount of time an actuator has been on over the past x minutes. This is to prevent the actuator from over-heating.

**My idea**
Storing current times in an array every time the actuator goes on (it is on for a fixed amount of time). When the oldest measurement is older than x minutes, it is removed from the array. If the array exceeds a certain size (e.g. certain amount of minutes the actuator has been on), a cool down period is started.

However, I feel there must be a more efficient / easy way to achieve this. How would you go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could simulate the temperature. Assume, you run the sim. periodically. If the actuator is on, a temp. value is increased in each iteration. If the actuator is off, the temp. value is decreased. If the temp. value goes over a certain limit, the actuator has to be disabled - to cool down. If the temp. value goes under a certain other limit, it's enabled again. While temp. value is over upper limit it shouldn't be increased anymore, same for lower limit and decrease.

Comment: The only sensible solution would be to solve this in hardware, because no matter how good you manage to design a software algorithm for this, you would still have no clue about ambient temperature. Consider placing a temp sensor or thermistor close to the actuator instead. Then software-wise, it's just about reading an ADC input and make decisions from there.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, has temperature sensor is the easiest way.
With array, there will be problem with the size, especially, if you want to count in minutes. For counting, there is also way for easier as following:

- T is the total time ON in last xx minutes as you expected. During initialization, it will be 0.
- If actuator is ON, so every check cycle (may be every s or smaller depend on your required), T will be increase value = cycle time
- If actuator is OFF: if T>0 then decrease value = cycle time, if T= 0, nothin to subtract more.